# Is it possible to name all labels in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

It is difficult to understand the code without labels in output using tkz-euclide.

> To name label all points using single **\tkzLabelPoints(all)**
>
> CODE from 
>   http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/euclide.html

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-6,xmax=12,ymin=-6,ymax=6] 
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoint(-5,-5){A} 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}  
    \tkzDefPoint(+5,-5){B} 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,-5){F}    
    \tkzDefPoint(+5,0){F'}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,+5){E} 
    \tkzDefPoint(-5,0){K}
    \tkzDefSquare(A,B)         \tkzGetPoints{C}{D}

    \tkzInterLC(D,C)(E,B)      \tkzGetPoints{T'}{T}

    \tkzDefMidPoint(D,T)     \tkzGetPoint{I}
    \tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,D,I)(E,D,I)   \tkzGetPoints{H'}{H}
    \tkzInterLC(O,H)(O,E)     \tkzGetPoints{M'}{M}
    \tkzInterCC(O,E)(E,M)     \tkzGetPoints{Q}{M}
    \tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,O,E)(Q,E,M)    \tkzGetPoints{P}{E}
    \tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,O,E)(P,E,M)    \tkzGetPoints{N}{Q} 

    \tkzCompass(O,H)
    \tkzCompass(E,H)
    \tkzDrawArc[color=gray,style=dashed](E,B)(T)  
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C,D)
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,E)  
    \tkzDrawSegments[color=gray](O,H E,H E,F F',K)
    \tkzDrawPoints(T,M,Q,P,N)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[color=red](M,E,Q,P,N)   
    \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Meaning of this (Unable to find in manual)

```
\tkzInterCC[with nodes](O,D,I)(E,D,I)   \tkzGetPoints{H'}{H}
```

Comment: Why not `\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,....) `?

Comment: I think it would be better to ask a new question about the meaning of `\tkzInterCC ...` seeing as it's quite different from your original question (labeling nodes), and you already have an answer for that.

Comment: Any news here. Solved or still open?(if yes you could accept the given answer)

Comment: I made a choice : init, def, calc, mark and label. It’s difficult to find a process to get a good place to the label in all cases. Like AndréC wrote, I prefer to customize!

Comment: knowing all points will be useful to understand the new code, But for final picture placement of label can be decided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\tkzLabelPoints(all)` option doesn't exist. You must enter all the names of the points  `\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,F',K,T,T',I,H,M,N,O,P,Q)` or make a foreach.

But as you can see, aesthetically this option always places the label on `below right` which is not necessarily the most beautiful aesthetic effect.

[image: label-default]

It is more aesthetic to customize the placement of each point as for example with this code:

```
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](C,T,H)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A,O,M,P)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](D)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](B,Q,N)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](E,I)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](F)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](K)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](F')
```

[image: label-custom]